# how exactly do Javascript numeric comparison operators handle strings?

Tags: javascript, string, comparison, operators, numeric

```
var i = ['5000','35000'];
alert((i[0] < i[1])?'well duh!':'fuzzy math?');
alert((Number(i[0]) < Number(i[1]))?'well duh!':'fuzzy math?');
```

What's happening here? In the first alert, the text string "5000" evaluates as *not* less than "35000". I assumed Javascript used Number() when numerically comparing strings, but apparently that's not the case. Just curious how exactly Javascript handles numerically comparing the strings of numbers by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript compares strings by character value, whether the strings look like numbers or not.

You can see this in the [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.8.5), section 11.8.5, point 4.

`'a' < 'b'` and `'ab' < 'ac` are both true.

Comment: Thanks! That point 4(a) string comparison prefix criteria is pretty interesting too.

Comment: Okay I'm still missing something -- I understand your examples above, but I don't understand how the character value of "5000" is not less than the character value of "35000". Can you run me through how the character values are calculated for my specific example?

Comment: @Wick: `"5"` is more than `"3"`.  This is a purely character-based comparison.

Comment: The spec link seems to have some new content now (art therapy for drug addictions).