# javascript string comparison in a foreign language

Tags: javascript

I have some old code that doesn't have any comments that is using javascript differently then how I've ever used it.  The following is doing math on strings.

```
if ((toFind > nextOptionText) && (toFind < lookAheadOptionText))
```

I've found questions like this one - that basically states that "a" < "b":

[how exactly do Javascript numeric comparison operators handle strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177238/how-exactly-do-javascript-numeric-comparison-operators-handle-strings/8177251#8177251)

However in my example I have some special characters that it is comparing against.  In my code the parameters from above are:

```
if (("A" > "+") && ("A" < ">EINFUHRUNG ZUM"))
```

This is equaling TRUE - For me in my case I need it to equal FALSE, but I'm not asking how to make it false, I really just want to understand what the developer that wrote this code was thinking and how does the above if statement work.

**Obviously I'm also dealing with a foreign language (German)** - I'm pretty sure that this code was written prior to the application becoming multi-lingual.
If there is other suggestions that I should look into, please let me know (i.e. like using the locale or doing a different type of comparison).

Comment: The `if` statement in your edit would evaluate to `false`, not `true`.  Can you post example code that shows the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My quick test shows that this code evaluates to FALSE, as expected.

```js
if (("A" > "+") && ("A" < ">EINFUHRUNG ZUM")) {
    alert('true')
} else {
    alert( 'false') 
}
```

In general, the comparison is done as usual [according to the character codes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp), therefore "A" > ">" and "A" > "+".

To compare strings with non-ASCII letters, you might find [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) useful.

Comment: I screwed up my original variables.  There were out of order.  I updated the question.

Comment: @webdad3, it doesn't change much: as long as the "standard" symbols (you have ">" in your string) are the first character, "A" (or any other letter) will be "greater" than the whole string.

Comment: your resources were very helpful in my understanding my issue.  Thanks!